# check return code from curl and if not 0 email admin

Tags: perl, curl, time

I am trying to check status of google aws servers using similar line to below:

time curl -k https://blablabla.azazonaws.com/ratingsvc

If the connection failed, times out, etc. I would like to email admin.

I am having trouble getting the error code into a variable

Comment: How are you running that command?

Comment: AWS is Amazon Web Services. So it has nothing to do with Google.

Answer (score 1):

To get further control of the HTTP GET (return codes, analyze the message contents, etc), I recommend the use of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm)

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('https://blablabla.azazonaws.com/ratingsvc');
```

and `$response` is an instance of [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Response.pm), so you can get total control of the GET response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to obtain the returned exit code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = 'time curl -k https://blablabla.azazonaws.com/ratingsvc';

my $return_code = system($command);

if ($return_code == 0) {
    print "Everything went well...\n";
} else {
    print "Oops... curl exited with code $return_code\n";
}
```

That will also print STDOUT and STDERR from curl to the screen but it will not affect your program. If you don't want to see the output of the command, you can add something to the end like >/dev/null, you'll still have your returned exit code.

HTH

Francisco